# Apply CSS to disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to view disabled button as:

[image]

The one marked with red is a disabled button and the green one is enabled.

I am trying to apply CSS to do the same as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btnSearch').attr("disabled", true);
     $("#btnSearch").css({ 'background': "#grey" });
 });
```

But its not showing up as mentioned in the image.

Its looking for me like this:

[image]

Which CSS attribute do I need to use for disabled buttons as above (marked in red)?

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/54qJx/

Comment: show us html for button. and share jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: `"#gray"` should be `grey`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no effect...i tried this

Comment: Ok, can you please put up a fiddle?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky   http://jsfiddle.net/54qJx/

Comment: @BearGrylls http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/54qJx/2/

Comment: r u sure you have the id "btnSearch" on the button?

Comment: use opacity to grayout button. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try out with `prop()`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').prop("disabled", true);
        $("#btnSearch").css({ 'background': "gray" });
 });
```

@BearGrylls
Check this updated [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Arb6e/), its working as per your requirement.

Comment: button is getting disabled but not viewing as mentioned in first image

Comment: @BearGrylls Check my updated answer and fiddle demo, its working as per your requirement, just try to change name of color.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `opacity` css for graying out `disabled` button :

```
$('#btnSearch').prop('disabled',true).css('opacity','0.5');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54qJx/8/)**

Comment: It's in his discretion whether he wants to use opacity or background-color. He doesn't **need** to use `opacity`.

Comment: @Padarom, He wants to see button disabled, and this is one of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply disable a button by this

```
$('#btnSearch').prop('disabled', true);
```

also change the background color with

```
$('#btnSearch').css('background-color', 'gray');
```

check the [.css() API](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for usage.

btw when using color name like gray, you don't need to put a '#' ahead of the name, that's why your setting of background color doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

css function should be like this to work.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').prop("disabled", true);
    $("#btnSearch").css('background-color','grey');

});
```

You can also use attr, but I prefer prop

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btnSearch").css('background-color','#ccc');

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CSS3 :disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp) selector, if you want to style it with CSS instead of Javascript:

```
#btnSearch:disabled {
   background-color: grey !important;
}
```

**edit:**

Your problem is, that your button is styled with an inline `style`-tag. It's generally a bad idea to use these, as it makes maintaining larger pages a nightmare. Read this article for more information: [Best Practices: Avoid Inline Styles for CSS](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm).

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54qJx/7/) for an example of how to do it anyways. What I'm doing here is using [this](http://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/) trick to override the inline style properties.

Answer (score 0):

Error in line `$("#btnSearch").css({ 'background': "#gray" });`

Try this

Your Button

`<button id="btnSearch" onclick="TeacherData_OnSearch()" style="background-color: #249FDA; color: white; height: 22px; width: 45px; border-radius: 4px;">Search</button>`

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSearch').attr("disabled", true);
    $('#btnSearch').css("background-color", '');
    $("#btnSearch").css({
        'background-color': "grey"
    });

})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/54qJx/4/)

Comment: `background` will override `background-color` so you can get rid of that line.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color won't grey won't make the button look like the two you have circled, as it looks like there is more CSS at work then simply setting the background to grey.

you can use

```
$("#btnSearch").css({ "element": "new value" });
```

But you might need to call it 4 or 5 times to get the desired effect with different elements.

Otherwise you can use

```
$("#btnSearch").addClass("disabled")
```

where disabled is a CSS class you've created with the correct styling (background grey, text colour darker etc). At a guess the two red circled buttons have had a class added to them to make them look disabled, so you can just add that class to the button you want to disable.

Comment: He doesn't necessarily need to add an additional class. He can just use the `:disabled`-selector on his disabled button. See my answer to see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use "#" with color. than you must use color HEX value not the name

Answer (score 0):

set a css class

```
.bg1 {background:#ddd}
```

then add it on button

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSearch').attr("disabled", true);
        $("#btnSearch").addClass("bg1");
});
```

Comment: Unnecessary. He already has the disabled-attribute, he doesn't need another class for it. His problem is the inline-CSS of the button. Look at his fiddle.